# Setting up Tomcat 6 JMX with LDAP Auth?

Tags: tomcat, active-directory, ldap, jmx

I'm trying to set up a Tomcat server with remote monitoring via JMX, with an LDAP authentication server.

All of this on a Windows machine.

I started with google, in which I found:
http://blogs.oracle.com/alanb/entry/one_password_to_rule_them

That seemed to be exactly what I was looking for, (using Java 1.6, Tomcat 6.0) but it is a bit vague for someone who hasn't used JMX or Java all that much.

Specifically, it doesn't explain where the: "ldap.config"  file is supposed to be placed, and my assumption of the JRE_HOME environmental variable folder seems to not be the correct place.

I also tried to enable the debug for the LDAP in his example, and it's not actually outputting anything to STD_OUT.

Using his example, this is how I have my config file is set up:

```
SunConfig {  
    com.sun.security.auth.module.LdapLoginModule REQUIRED  
    userProvider="ldap://sun-ds/ou=people,dc=sun,dc=com"  
    userFilter="(&(uid={USERNAME})(objectClass=inetOrgPerson))"  
    authzIdentity=monitorRole  
    useSSL=false;  
    debug=true  
};
```

I apologize if I am missing something obvious to the more experienced, but I am just missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/login/ConfigFile.html will give you some ideas.

As a minimum, you can copy the file to ${user.home}/.java.login.config instead.

Comment: I have found in my research that JAAS supports setting up LDAP, but Tomcat doesn't actually support it out of the box.

Comment: Did you also find out whats needed for Tomcat to support it?